# Controller: No user id with axios api-call?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, axios

I built a '*save*' method in vue with axios for use with laravel (for logged in users with auth):

```
save: function(status) {
     axios.post('/api/save-question', this.Frage)
        .then(res => {
            this.$router.push('/');
            })
}
```

**api.php:**

```
Route::post('/save-question','FragenController@store');
```

that leads to the controller method 'store' in **FragenController.php**:

Inside this method I want to validate the user id, to see if the current user is allowed to save, like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $UserID = Auth::user()->id;
        if($UserID=='1'){
          //do the saving part
        }
    }
```

But that doesn't work it seems, since this variable is empty. Now I'm wondering, if the axios call is made from a neutral user without an id (not the currently loggedin laravel user).
Is that the case or am I just doing it wrong? The saving works fine if I manually set the $UserID='1'.

Comment: `since this variable is empty` you mean `null`?

Comment: empty/null yes, I'm not sure which one. But since @LobsterBaz 's answer I probably won't look depper into it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using API routes, your user doesn't have a session and your backend has no ways to know which user is authenticated.

The solution is to use API tokens to verify if your user is authenticated. Laravel already thought of this and makes it easy for us.

For Laravel 7+, it's provided in a separate package called Laravel Sanctum:

- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum

On previous versions, it was included in Laravel under API Authentication:

- https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication